# Integration: Branch cuts

Tags: integration, branch-cuts

Can someone show me how to calculate this integral using branch cuts ?

$$\int_0^{\infty}\Big(\frac{x}{1-x}\Big)^{\frac{1}{3}}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$$

Comment: By changing the upper integration limit to $1$ we have $I=\dfrac\pi{\sqrt[3]4}~\bigg(1-\dfrac1{\sqrt3}\bigg)$, as @JackD'Aurizio already wrote. As for the remainder, from $1$ to $\infty$, the best way of writing it is in terms of the [hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) $-\dfrac32\cdot~_3F_2\bigg(~\bigg\{1~,~1~,~\dfrac12\bigg\}~;~ \bigg\{\dfrac43~,~\dfrac56\bigg\}~;-1\bigg)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$f(z)=\frac{|z|^{1/3}e^{i\varphi_1/3}|z-1|^{-1/3}e^{-i\varphi_2/3}}{1+z^2}$$
where $\varphi_1=\arg{z}$, $\varphi_2=\arg(z-1)$, $0\le\varphi_1,\varphi_2\le2\pi$. Integrating $f(z)$ over a dumbbell contour, we get
\begin{align}
\int_\gamma f(z)\ dz
&=\int^1_0\frac{x^{1/3}e^{i(0)/3}(1-x)^{-1/3}e^{-i(\pi)/3}}{1+x^2}dx+\int^0_1\frac{x^{1/3}e^{i(2\pi)/3}(1-x)^{-1/3}e^{-i(\pi)/3}}{1+x^2}dx\\
&=-i\sqrt{3}\int^1_0\frac{x^{1/3}(1-x)^{-1/3}}{1+x^2}dx\\
&=2\pi i\left(\sum_\pm\operatorname*{Res}_{z=\pm i}f(z)-\color{grey}{\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0}\frac{(1-z)^{-1/3}}{1+z^2}}\right)\\
&=2\pi i\left(\frac{e^{\pi i/6}\times2^{-1/6}\times e^{-\pi i/4}-e^{\pi i/2}\times2^{-1/6}\times e^{-5\pi i/12}}{2i}\right)\\
&=-i\frac{\pi}{\sqrt[3]{4}}\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)
\end{align}
which implies
$$\int^1_0\frac{x^{1/3}(1-x)^{-1/3}}{1+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt[3]{4}}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$
For the remaining integral, one can apply the substitution $x\mapsto 1-x^3$ to get
\begin{align}
\int^1_0\frac{(x-1)^{-1/3}}{1+x^2}
&=-\int^1_0\frac{3x}{(x^3-1)^2+1}dx\\
&=-\sum_{\omega\in S}\frac{1}{2(\omega^4-\omega)}\int^1_0\frac{x-\sigma+it}{(x-\sigma)^2+t^2}dx\\
&=-\sum_{\omega\in S}\frac{1}{2(\omega^4-\omega)}\left[\frac{1}{2}\ln\left((x-\sigma)^2+t^2\right)+i\arctan\left(\frac{x-\sigma}{t}\right)\right]^1_0\\
&=-\sum_{\omega\in S}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{(1-\sigma)^2+t^2}{\sigma^2+t^2}\right)+2i\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1-\sigma}{t}\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{\sigma}{t}\right)\right)}{4(\omega^4-\omega)}
\end{align}
where $\omega=\sigma+it$, $\sigma\in\mathbb{R}$ and $$S=\left\{\sqrt[6]{2}e^{\pi i/12},\sqrt[6]{2}e^{7\pi i/12},\sqrt[6]{2}e^{3\pi i/4},\sqrt[6]{2}e^{5\pi i/4},\sqrt[6]{2}e^{17\pi i/12},\sqrt[6]{2}e^{23\pi i/12}\right\}$$
Writing out the $6$ terms manually then using Mathematica to simplify, we find that the sum (which is equivalent to a hypergeometric function as pointed out by Lucian) evaluates to
\begin{align}
\frac{3}{2}{}_3\mathrm{F}_2\left(\left.\begin{matrix}1,1,\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{4}{3},\frac{5}{6}\end{matrix}\right|-1\right)
=&\ \frac{\pi\sqrt[3]{2}}{12}(3+\sqrt{3})+\frac{\ln{2}}{3\sqrt[3]{4}}+\frac{\ln(\sqrt[3]{2}-1)}{4\sqrt[3]{4}}-\frac{\ln(2+\sqrt[3]{4}+\sqrt[3]{16})}{2\sqrt[3]{4}}\\
&+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt[3]{4}}\operatorname{artanh}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{5-\sqrt[3]{4}}}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt[3]{4}}\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{16}-1}{\sqrt{3}+1}\right)\\
&-\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2\sqrt[3]{4}}\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt[3]{16}+1}{\sqrt{3}-1}\right)-\frac{\arctan(1+\sqrt[3]{2})}{\sqrt[3]{4}}
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0\frac{x^{1/3}(1-x)^{-1/3}}{1+x^2}dx
=&\ -\frac{\pi\sqrt[3]{2}}{12}(3+\sqrt{3})-\frac{\ln{2}}{3\sqrt[3]{4}}-\frac{\ln(\sqrt[3]{2}-1)}{4\sqrt[3]{4}}+\frac{\ln(2+\sqrt[3]{4}+\sqrt[3]{16})}{2\sqrt[3]{4}}\\
&-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt[3]{4}}\operatorname{artanh}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{5-\sqrt[3]{4}}}\right)-\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt[3]{4}}\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{16}-1}{\sqrt{3}+1}\right)\\
&+\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2\sqrt[3]{4}}\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt[3]{16}+1}{\sqrt{3}-1}\right)+\frac{\arctan(1+\sqrt[3]{2})}{\sqrt[3]{4}}\\
&+\frac{\pi}{\sqrt[3]{4}}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)
\end{align}
[image]

Comment: For the power of contour integration (+1).

Answer (score -1):

Using the simple substitution $x\mapsto \tan(x)$, we get that

$$\int_0^{\infty}\Big(\frac{x}{1-x}\Big)^{\frac{1}{3}}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\Big(\frac{\tan(x)}{1-\tan(x)}\Big)^{\frac{1}{3}} \ dx$$

where the last integral can be computed by Mathematica as shown below.

$$\frac{1}{48 \sqrt[3]{2}}\Re\left(\sqrt{3} \log (4) \sqrt[3]{-1-i}-24 i \log \left(-\sqrt[3]{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}}\right) \sqrt[3]{-1-i}+12 i \log \left(-(-1)^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}}\right) \sqrt[3]{-1-i}+12 \sqrt{3} \log \left(-(-1)^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}}\right) \sqrt[3]{-1-i}+24 i \log \left(\sqrt[3]{-2}-\sqrt[3]{-1-i}\right) \sqrt[3]{-1-i}-12 i \log \left(\sqrt[3]{-2}-(-1)^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{-1-i}\right) \sqrt[3]{-1-i}-12 \sqrt{3} \log \left(\sqrt[3]{-2}-(-1)^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{-1-i}\right) \sqrt[3]{-1-i}-12 i \log \left(\sqrt[3]{1+i}+\sqrt[3]{-2}\right) \sqrt[3]{-1-i}+12 \sqrt{3} \log \left(\sqrt[3]{1+i}+\sqrt[3]{-2}\right) \sqrt[3]{-1-i}+\left(-1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \pi  \sqrt[3]{-1-i}+\left(-2 i \sqrt[3]{-1-i}-8 i \sqrt[3]{-1+i}+8 \sqrt{3} \sqrt[3]{-1+i}\right) \log (2)-12 i \sqrt[3]{-1+i} \log \left(\sqrt[3]{-1+i} \sqrt[3]{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)+12 \sqrt{3} \sqrt[3]{-1+i} \log \left(\sqrt[3]{-1+i} \sqrt[3]{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)+24 \sqrt[3]{-1+i} i \log \left(-\sqrt[3]{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}}\right)-12 i \sqrt[3]{-1+i} \log \left(-(-1)^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}}\right)-12 \sqrt[3]{-1+i} \sqrt{3} \log \left(-(-1)^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}}\right)+12 \sqrt[3]{-1+i} i \log \left(\sqrt[3]{-1} \left(2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{-1+i}+2\right)\right)-12 \sqrt[3]{-1+i} \sqrt{3} \log \left(\sqrt[3]{-1} \left(2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{-1+i}+2\right)\right)-24 i \sqrt[3]{-1+i} \log \left(\sqrt[3]{-2}-\sqrt[3]{-1+i}\right)+12 \sqrt{3} \sqrt[3]{-1+i} \log \left(\sqrt[3]{-2}-(-1)^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{-1+i}\right)+12 \sqrt[3]{-1+i} i \log \left(\sqrt[3]{-2}-(-1)^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{-1+i}\right)\right)$$

Comment: This answer is *probably* wrong, for the following reason: For *negative* values of *n* and *odd* values of *k*, both *Maple* and *Mathematica* consider $\sqrt[\large^k]n$ to be the complex quantity which forms the smallest positive angle with the positive horizontal semi-axis $(Ox$. E.g., $\sqrt[^3]{-1}=\dfrac{1+i\sqrt3}2$ as opposed to $-1$.

Comment: @Lucian I took this form of answer from Mathematica and numerically things seem correct.

Comment: The numerical result is about $-0.2561547115267227729.$ Is this what you get ?

Comment: @Lucian I get $\approx 1.382763392139544$.